# How to do a recursive grep (search) and automatically look inside archive files especially jar ones?

Tags: search, find, grep, text-search

I am looking for a command that would work like `grep -r sometext .` but that will know to look inside archives (at least `.jar`).

Extra bonus ;) if we can make it ignore directories like `.svn` `.hg`.

Answer (score 0):

The low-tech solution:

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec jar tf '{}' \| grep -H "SearchTerm" \;
```

If you do that sort of thing often, consider replacing grep with [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) (plus it does avoid version control directories by default)

Comment: ack won't look inside .jar files, though.  Plugins to handle them are on deck for ack 2.1, though.